# How to add data to a patch plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am using distmesh to mesh a sphere which I cut into a hemisphere after. Currently the major is with the output of `isosurface`:

```
pv=isosurface(x,y,z,reshape(fd([x(:),y(:),z(:)],varargin{:}),size(x)),0);

p=pv.vertices;

t=pv.faces;

p1 = patch('faces',T,'vertices',P,'facecol',[.8,.9,1],'edgecol','k');
```

I need to add more vertices to the surface, not sure how to do it, any help would be appreciated.